# type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'List<bool>' of 'function result'

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a collapsible listView.

So that each item of my list handle the click individually, I created a list of bool. But when I build the page I have this error.
I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Can you help me ?

```
List<bool> toogleList;

Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(23, 0, 20, 20),
  child: ListView.builder(
    physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: widget.responseDaily['list'].length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
      setState(() {
        toogleList.insert(index, false);
      });
      return InkWell(
        onTap: (){
          setState(() {
            toogleList[index] = !toogleList[index];
          });
        },
        child: Flexible(
          flex: 2,
          fit: FlexFit.tight,
          child: RotationTransition(
            turns: (toogleList[index] == false) ? AlwaysStoppedAnimation(0) : AlwaysStoppedAnimation(180 / 360),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.expand_less,
              size: 16,
            ),
         ),
       ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: List<bool> toogleList; = [];

Comment: thank you for your answer but it doesn't change anything

Comment: Is there anywhere else you are accessing the `toogleList` ? @bchoisy

Comment: onTap() is the index printed correctly. Is it the same number you have clicked?

Comment: @void no just here

Comment: @VisakhVijayan I cannot display the list because of the error. so i can't click

Comment: Oh no no sorry.  I mean remove setState calls and just check if u r getting the index clicked. I remember I faced an issue once.

Comment: @VisakhVijayan thanks to your comment, i checked my code and there is another place i use tooglelist. I edit my post. my bad

Comment: @VisakhVijayan when I remove setState calls, I still have the same error but at the RoationTransition level

Comment: I am not sure why you are calling setState inside the builder. Anyways I went ahead and ran your code and it worked for me. Since the answer can't be pasted here I have written it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class _HmeState extends State<Hme> 
{

    List<bool> toogleList = [false, false, false];

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context)
    {

        return MaterialApp
        (
            home: Scaffold
            (
                body: Container
                (
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: ListView.builder
                    (
                        itemCount: 3,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index)
                        {
                            return Card
                            (
                                child: InkWell
                                (
                                    child: Text(toogleList[index].toString()),
                                    onTap: ()
                                    {
                                        print(index);
                                        setState(()
                                        {
                                            toogleList[index] = !toogleList[index];
                                        });
                                    },
                                )
                            );
                        }
                    )
                )
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: On clicking false you will see the particular inkwell changes to true and vice-versa. The true can false states can be your collapsibles

Comment: thanks you. it was the set state call inside the builder.

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't be calling `setState` when the `ListView` is building it's items. If you do, you get an error for that.

Second, your logic will keep inserting `false` on each item click and the `bool` values would not change as expected( they will always be true when multiple clicks on an item happens`:

INSTEAD:

Generate a list of `bool` which have their values set to `false`:

```
  List<bool> toogleList = List.generate(widget.responseDaily['list'].length, (index) => false);
```

Change the values when a tap/click on the item is detected:

```
 onTap: () {
     setState(() {
     toogleList[index] = !toogleList[index];
     });
   },
```

Answer (score 1):

It can happen if you transform a boolean into a list of boolean and you (or Android Studio) use hot reload. (CTRL + )

Use a hot restart (SHIFT + F10) and the error will be gone.